# Uncheck checkbox and hide parent when button is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

The following code I wrote is supposed to have a row of check boxes, and when selected, displays the label of that check box in a separate div.

```
     <div class="span3" id="bill">
          <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="" id="item1" checked="checked">
            Item1 - Price
          </label>
          <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="" id="item2" checked="checked">
            Item2 - Price
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="span3" id="currBill">
          <label id="item1_lb">
            Item1 - Price
          </label>
          <label id="item2_lb">
            Item2 - Price
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <button class="btn" id="pay">Pay</button>
      </div>
```

the following js takes care of displaying the labels when selected/unselected (It's sloppy for know, all the check boxes will later be filled in from a database, this is just some place holding code for the general idea of my problem.)

Neither of the two functions seem to be working, the on click function at least triggers, but doesn't actually hide anything. Any ideas?

```
$(function() {
  $('input:checkbox').bind('change',(function() {
    $('#'+ithis.id+'_lb').toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
  });

  $("#pay").click(function() {
    $("#bill input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
      if($(this).checked)
      {
        $(this).parent().hide();
        $(this).checked = false;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Browser Console to check the errors (press `Ctrl+Shift+J`). You have the following errors:

- In line 2 `('change',(function()`, drop the parenthesis before `function` keyword.
- `ithis.id` should be `this.id`.
- Instead check `if($(this).checked)` should be like you did first: `if($(this).is(':checked'))`
- To deselect the checkbox use `$(this).prop('checked', false);`

**Fiddle here:** http://jsfiddle.net/qKPGd/

Comment: Thank you! It appears that simply unchecking the checkbox in the second function doesn't trigger the first function which should hide the secondary labels, how should that be handled?

I could just repeat that one line of code I suppose, but that doesn't seem proper.

Comment: @dk.win: There is no problem with repeat 1 line, if there are more than 2 or 3, build a function for that, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/qKPGd/1/

Answer (score 2):

`$(this).checked` tries to access a jQuery collection attribute `checked`.  You can alter element properties via the `.prop` method.

```
if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    ...
    $(this).prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm brand new to web dev and there's so much to pick up.